# Showing model associations in the views of rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

By default my model associations show up in the 'Add New' tab of rails_admin. However, if I modify the rails_admin.rb file and use config.model to customize what fields appear in the view, it obviously will remove it from the view.

In my example, I have a Customer and a User.

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
      :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

   # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
   attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :role,     :company, :customer_id

   belongs_to :customer
end
```

Customer.rb

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :city, :name, :state, :street, :zip, :container_id, :user_id

  has_many :users
end
```

So now if I log in to the rails_admin dashboard and go to add a new user, I have a droppdown option to select a Customer, a button to add a new customer, and a button to edit a customer. However, once I add my config.model in rails_admin.rb.

rails_admin.rb

```
config.model 'User' do
      list do
         field :name do
            label "Name"
         end
         field :email do
            label "Email"
         end
         field :company do
            label "Company"
     end
     field :role do
        label "Role"
     end
  end
  edit do
     field :name do
        label "Name"
     end
     field :email do
        label "Email"
     end
     field :company do
        label "Company"
     end
     field :role do
        label "Role"
     end
     field :role, :enum do
        enum do
           ['1a', '1b', '2a', '2b', '3a', '3b', '4a', '4b', '5']
        end
        label "Role"
     end
  end
  create do
     field :name do
        label "Name"
     end
     field :email do
        label "Email"
        help "The email address will serve as the username."
     end
     field :password do
        label "Password"
     end
     field :password_confirmation do
        label "Password Confirmation"
        help "Required"
     end
     field :company do
        label "Company"
     end
     field :role, :enum do
        enum do
           ['1a', '1b', '2a', '2b', '3a', '3b', '4a', '4b', '5']
        end
        label "Role"
     end
     end
   end
```

This will override the association fields that I have when I want to add a user. My question is what is the syntax I should use in rails_admin to explicitly tell the rails_admin config that I would like the model association to show up when I go to add a user in rails_admin.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In your `rails_admin.rb` file, where is it your custom configuration block, you just need declare the association like this:

```
config.model 'User' do
  configure :customer, :belongs_to_association
...
...
```

And use the above key as field name:

```
edit do
  field :customer do
    label "Customer"
  end
end
```

Comment: `configure :customer, :belongs_to_association` is not necessary for rails_admin 0.6.7 btw